# Could I use Pappus' Hexagon Theorem as forces Triangle?

Tags: forces, mathematics, geometry

Suppose I represent 2 forces as vectors and set 3 points there proportionally (divide the 2 vectors by 3).
If I now draw the connections according to Pappus' Hexagon theory, does the intersection line give the vector of the resulting forces (orientation)?

Answer (score 0):

yes it gives the direction, just try it out and see the proof yourself. But why do it in this more complicated way instead of just adding the vectors or equal parts of theM?